# how to make check box check on button click in different activity in android

Tags: android, button, checkbox

in my android app there is terms and condition fragment and in that there are two buttons accept and decline, the scenario is when user click on terms and condition the fragment open and user have two options accept and declined and when he press the accept button it return to main activity and there is one checkbox that should be check when user click on accept button in the fragment,So can anyone tell me how should i do that?

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: i am not getting any idea how do i do that so i just created one registration activity there is button terms and condition and one check box,user can check that check box there itself but if he want to read the terms and condition then there is fragment and its called when user click on terms and condition and there are two buttons to accept and declined and when he click on accept button he return to registration activity and the check box should gets automatically check and when he click on decline then it should not.

Answer (score 1):

By using `SharedPreferences` short quick example:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putBoolean("switchOn", true);
editor.commit();
```

on the second activity

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
Editor editor = pref.edit();
boolean buttonOn = editor.getBoolean("switchOn", false);
```

Comment: so from the above example when the user click on accept then the Boolean button makes it true and then i have to check that if it is true or false and then make my check box checked?

Comment: @NikhilPatil exactly

Comment: ok just a one question in fragment activity i call editor.putBoolean("switchon",true); and and in registration activity i call boolean button = editor.getBoolean("switchon",false);

Comment: yes you put this: editor.putBoolean("switchon",true);inside the onclicklistener of the button and on the other activity you check if its true or false by calling get;

Comment: i am not getting getBoolean() methode in activity i that i am checking for its false or true..

Comment: i am not getting that there is only putBoolean option comming.

Comment: i suggest you read a bit about shared preferences this will help you, the code i provided was totally blind code. see this for : https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html